# Why aren't the catenoid and helicoid globally isometric?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I was reading do Carmo just now and there he proves that the catenoid is locally isometric to the helicoid, but I wondered why it couldn't be extended to a global isometry and I couldn't figure it out. I'm sure it must be something relatively obvious that I'm missing, so I'd appreciate some help.

**EDIT:** I think the following argument can be given (but I'm not really sure): we know that intrinsic distance (i.e the infimum of the length of all paths connecting two points) is invariant by isometries and is always at least $\|p - q\|$ (viewing points on the surface as points in $\mathbb{R}^3$).  But the intrinsic distance $Y(0,0)=(0,0,0)$ and $Y(0,3\pi) = (0,0,3\pi)$ is evidently $3\pi$, while (background: parameterizing on $[0,2\pi) \times \mathbb{R}$ the catenoid by $X(u,v)=(\cosh(v)\cos(u), \cosh(v)\sin(u), v)$ and the helicoid by $Y(u,v) = (\sinh(v)\cos(u), \sinh(v)\sin(u), v)$) the intrinsic distance of $X(0,0)$ and $X(0,3\pi)$ is greater than or equal to $\sqrt{2 + 9\pi^2} > 3\pi$. We conclude that there exists no global isometry between the catenoid and the helicoid.

Comment: they are not homeomorphic

Comment: @WillJagy why is that?

Comment: the catenoid is not simply connected, it is a surface of revolution.. let me see what I can find

Comment: "Using the above structure theorem for disks, Meeks and Rosenberg (10) proved that the plane and the helicoid are the only complete properly embedded simply connected minimal surfaces in R3"  from https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1544050/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was hoping for a proof which didn't use so much though (I certainly couldn't just cite a paper if this was asked in an exam), so I'll wait for another answer.

Comment: I was just looking for a quote that clearly stated that the helicoid is simply connected. Far easier to conclude that the catenoid is not. Put together, not homeomorphic.

Comment: I see. Well, I'd still be more satisfied with a simpler proof sketch... proving the helicoid is simply connected isn't very easy.

Comment: The catenoid $r = c. \cosh z/c $ is a tight scroll of an infinite number of coinciding periodic surfaces of revolution  isometric to "developed" or laid out infinite strip mappable along $r=c$ to $u=0$ in the developed state. Both are simply connected in homeomorphism.

Comment: It's not hard to see that the helicoid is simply connected. As embedded in $\Bbb{R}^3$ on [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid) with $\alpha=1$, we can see that there is a retract from $\Bbb{R}^3$ to the helicoid defined by $(x,y,z) \mapsto (C\cos z, C\sin z, z)$, where $C=(x,y)\cdot (\cos z,\sin z)$. (I.e., take the rotating projection). Thus the fundamental group of the helicoid is a subgroup of the fundamental group of $\Bbb{R}^3$, and therefore trivial.

Comment: Similarly, the catenoid retracts to a circle, and therefore has a fundamental group which contains $\Bbb{Z}$ as a subgroup.

Comment: @jgon Thanks! I could say I regret not having clearly stated I wanted an argument which didn't use any algebraic topology but then I wouldn't have read this beautiful solution. I appreciate it. I was looking for something more along the lines of my edit (which I think is right) but I really liked these arguments.

Comment: @MatheusAndrade That's reasonable, I suspected you wanted something other than algebraic topology, but I figured I might as well post these ideas as comments. :)